# BPM Workspace is too slow while logging in with any user

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I have my admin and soa server up and running on Windows platform and I can login in console and em without any hassle. The only problem I am facing with workspace. When I login in workpace with admin user or any other user, it does not redirect to the next page and keeps on loading on the same. I checked in soa logs and there found the below exception:

Caused by: weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction has timed out when making request to XAResource 'SOADataSource_obpm_domain'
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAResourceDescriptor.startResourceUse(XAResourceDescriptor.java:673)
        ... 20 more

```
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1678)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1577)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.getXAConn(JTAConnection.java:215)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.checkConnection(JTAConnection.java:84)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection.checkConnection(JTAConnection.java:74)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.preInvocationHandler(Connection.java:100)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_XAConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection.dequeue(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone please help on this?